# Ecmascript reserved word work around

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

I am working on a project which is built on Novell Operations Center which has a scripting engine based on Ecmascript. I am able to address objects in the Java API on which the software is running.

I am trying to remove a file from the file system using the standard Java java.io.File class.

The script is as followed:

```
var file = new java.io.File('file_path');
file.delete();
```

This throws an error because "delete" is a reserved word in Ecmascript/Javascript.
Even if I use `eval('file.delete()');` I get the same error. Statements like `file.exists()` or `file.canWrite()` run as expected.

I am looking for a possible work around to be able to call the delete method on a file object. The deleteOnExit() method won't work because the server software will not exit on a regular base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You always can use the *bracket notation*:

```
file[ 'delete' ]();
```